# iOS: Convert UIImage to base64 without UIImageRepresentation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I think everything is in the title:
I have a UIImage that I need to convert to base64 **without using** *UIImagePNGRepresentation* or *UIImageJPEGRepresentation*. Objective C is what I code in.

Is this possible?

Comment: The size will be larger.

Comment: I am just trying to get the image by any means without affecting memory. And so far, the representations are incompatible with my (phone gap) app.

Comment: Wondering why do you need Base64?

Comment: Because I need the image. And I thought that getting it through base64 might be easier on the memory?

Comment: Going to Base64 will increase the size of the data, 4 bytes for every 3 and requires an extra operation on the data. Base64 is generally used to convert raw data into a string format when raw data transfer and/or display is inappropriate. But still mysterious is "getting it", what is the usage?

Comment: Oh sorry, I need the image to pass it to a sharing plugin in order to share a screenshot. I was thinking that maybe if instead of saving to the temporary folder, it would be more efficient if I passed it directly in base64 and displayed it there.

Comment: It's like pulling teeth to get the information, consider if you are on my side. "pass it to a sharing plugin" means on the iOS device? If so just pass the UIImage reference. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, it is a sharing plugin for phone gap that gives you access to native sharing dialogs. It accepts either a path to an image or a base64 string. Thus, I don't think a UIImage reference would work.
This whole approach stems from trying to find a solution to my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876228/ios-phonegap-screenshot-plugin-kills-css-animations

Answer (score 3):

When converting to base64 string:

```
NSData *imageBase64Data = [ImageData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];

NSString *imageBase64String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageBase64Data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And converting it back:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:string options:0];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

as you can see from the code, we just converted the string back to data(originally image)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the image to NSData without assigning a png or jpg representation like this:

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage);
NSData* data = (id)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(provider));
```

Then convert the data to a base64 string using a library like this one: https://github.com/ekscrypto/Base64

Comment: Are you sure that this works with UIImage? I am getting a "No visible interface for UIImage declares the selector base64String"

Comment: It needs NSData. You should be able to get the raw data (without UIImagePNGRepresentation, etc) with something like:

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage);
    NSData* data = (id)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(provider));

Comment: Sorry, should have put that in the answer. I've edited it to include that.

Comment: Better than a 3rd party solution use the `NSData` method: `base64EncodedStringWithOptions: `, available in iOS 7.0 and later..